# Self Referential Data (recursive datastructure): Cannot Reference Field before it is defined java

Tags: java, recursive-datastructures

thanks for the assistance. I have some self referential data, and I can't seem to figure out how to use the information without getting this error.

"Cannot reference a field before it is defined"

```
class Bus {
  String name;
  Location destination;

  Bus(String name, Location destination){
    this.name = name;
    this.destination = destination;
  }
}

class Location {
  String name;
  Bus busToLocation;

  Location(String name, Bus busToLocation){
    this.name = name;
    this.busToLocation = busToLocation;
  }
}

class Examples{
  Bus bus1 = new Bus("Charlie", loc1);
  Location loc1 = new Location("USA", bus1);
}
```

Of course, this makes sense because Java operates on a top down basis. Unfortunately I can't just change the order to

```
Location loc1 = new Location("USA", bus1);
Bus bus1 = new Bus("Charlie", loc1);
```

Since I'm still left with the same problem.

I have considered trying something like initially creating a null pointer (like you might in some other languages)

```
class Examples{
  Bus bus1;
  Location loc1;

  bus1 = new Bus("Charlie", loc1);
  loc1 = new Location("USA", bus1);
}
```

But I'm fairly certain you can't do this in Java. (It's illegal syntax)

What's the best way to go about this? Thanks!

Edit: This is a simplification of the actual code. In the real code, the buses are several class layers deep and are within a self referential list so it's much more difficult to use setters to change them after the fact. If possible I'd like to find a solution that doesn't require setters.

Comment: You can create the object and set the Bus/Location after the object instantiation, using a setter method.

Comment: @Cλstor this is a simplification of the problem. In the real problem, the Buses are actually several layers deep and within a self referential list, so it's not as practical to do it this way. If possible I was looking for a solution that does not require using a setter.

Comment: In your design you allow only 1 bus per location and vice versa, isn't that an issue? But if you want to stick with it, it would be straight forward to apply a setter, e.g. for `Location.bus` in the constructor of `Bus` and you could create a Bus/Location pair using `new Bus("Charlie", new Location("Bravo"))`, no matter how deep buses are nested. Probably a more comprehensive MRE is needed here.

Comment: @curiosa this is a simplification of the problem, in the actual problem there are a list of features for each location, some of which are buses. The code I put up focuses on what I consider the essence of the problem. I honestly consider the requirements of having to have the actual bus objects inside of each location and vise versa bad design (but that's what the assignment required). Normally in cases like this I'd just put the names of the buses inside and then I'd have a function that would obtain a bus object with that name when given the name of a bus.